# JAX-RS Client PUT/POST request: unable to an entity(Object) in the body

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I use bog-standard JAX-RS client code as below (borrowed from https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client
):

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();       
Amount amount = new Amount("GBP", totalSavings);
       Response response = client.target(TRANSFER_TO_SAVINGS_GOAL_REST_URI)
                    .resolveTemplate("accountUid", accountUid)
                    .resolveTemplate("savingsGoalUid", savingsUid)
                    .request()
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + customerToken)
                    .put(Entity.json(amount));
```

Now, that fails, as in returning 400 Bad request.

On the receiving end, the sent entity (`amount`) is null. Any idea why?

I'm checking in debugger and the entity has got a bona fide value, but if I build a test @Post end point as below:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/account/{accountUid}/savings-goals/{savingsGoalUid}/add-money/{transferUid}")
public Response getUserHistory(String amount,
                               @PathVariable("accountUid") UUID accountUid,
                               @PathVariable("savingsGoalUid") UUID savingsGoalUid,
                               @PathVariable("transferUid") UUID transferUid) {
    log.info("Amount: " , amount);

    return null;
}
```

That does confirm the amount is empty.

Any help please?

Comment: what is stopping you from creating your own Response type and adding the error message(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, that hopefully could be helpful to someone, is:

this last bit:

```
...
Entity.json(amount);
```

Did not produce required JSON structure for `Amount`. Required:

```
{
  "amount": {
    "currency": "GBP",
    "minorUnits": 1
  }
}
```

Generated:

```
{ "currency": "GBP",
  "minorUnits": 1
}
```

To fix the problem, I've added the following 2 annotations go my `Amount` class:

```
@JsonTypeName("amount")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = NAME)
public class Amount {
    private String currency;
    private long minorUnits;
}
```

That produced required JSON format.

To check the value of the JSON in the request, I used the followig:

```
response.readEntity(String.class)
```

That printed the JSON string for `amount`

Answer (score 0):

On one end Amount is an object, and on the other amount is a simple string. Have you tried on your `getUserHistory` method creating an `Amount` class ?

Then you could do something like this :

```
@PutMapping(value = "/account/{accountUid}/savings-goals/{savingsGoalUid}/add-money/{transferUid}")
public Response getUserHistory(Amount amount,
                               @PathVariable("accountUid") UUID accountUid,
                               @PathVariable("savingsGoalUid") UUID savingsGoalUid,
                               @PathVariable("transferUid") UUID transferUid) {
    log.info("Amount: " , amount);

    return null;
}
```

If you're expecting to receive json then I think mapping a full json object to string would not work

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you A Le Dref, the amount is not passed at all - the log statement prints just `Amount: `. I don't think it's a conversion thing - otherwise I'd get a wrong media exception or something similar I'd think. The problem is : nothing is passed in the request body :(